# "On the fly" scaffolding in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am about to start a project where *input (form) models* are coming from runtime loaded assemblies. I need to generate html form for these models. Either on-the-fly or cached somehow. As far as my experience goes, scaffolding a cshtml view from the model is a design-time task.

Is there any core or third-party library that allows me to do the same at runtime?

Something that takes a runtime model class, and - based on the data annotation and validation attributes - it generates something like an ASP.NET Core MVC `.cshtml` partial view in memory. Or relevant parts of it.

My searches yielded no result. I am aware that *Razor class library (RCL)* could be an alternative, but I would rather not allow plugin developers to interfere that deep.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by runtime loaded assemblies? Are they loaded during some unknown point in time while the application is running? Do you not have them available when building your application?

Comment: @funatparties No plugin-enabled system will have all its potential plugins available at design time. That means in my case, that models are coming from assemblies loaded dynamically at best at the start, at worst at any point in time. Using `AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath` for example.

Comment: Then you'd need to provide more information on what do you plan on doing with these html files after they are generated. It's easy enough to load the class, attribute and method definitions using System.Reflection.

Comment: @funatparties I am aware, that I could replicate generation. But I'd rather not do this if there is any ready-made solution. Although I don't think that it makes any difference, for the sake of simplicity, let's say I will complile the cshtml files, cache the compiled version, and in specific situations, I will get them through the Razor pipeline like RenderPartial does.